# Visual Studio 2019 problem with static library projects

Tags: visual-studio, visual-c++

I am trying to build a project consisting on a c++ console application and a c++ static library. I just create a default project for both. Visual Studio creates a default example function. I include that function also in the header file so that it's exported. Then I add the reference to the library project from the console project. Then I try to build the project and it fails saying there is an undefined reference to the function in the library. But if I include the generated .lib file in the console project it works. I have used static libraries in Visual Studio thousands of times but have no idea what is going on now.

I am using Visual Studio Community:

Microsoft Visual Studio Community 2019
Version 16.1.3
VisualStudio.16.Release/16.1.3+29009.5
Microsoft .NET Framework
Version 4.7.03190

Installed Version: Community

Visual C++ 2019   00435-60000-00000-AA098
Microsoft Visual C++ 2019

Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio Package   9.1.00429.1
Application Insights Tools for Visual Studio

ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019   16.1.429.50124
ASP.NET and Web Tools 2019

Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0   16.1.429.50124
Azure App Service Tools v3.0.0

C# Tools   3.1.1-beta4-19281-06+58a4b1e79aea28115e66b06f850c83a3f1fcb6d3
C# components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Common Azure Tools   1.10
Provides common services for use by Azure Mobile Services and Microsoft Azure Tools.

Cookiecutter   16.1.19129.1
Provides tools for finding, instantiating and customizing templates in cookiecutter format.

Microsoft Azure Tools   2.9
Microsoft Azure Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio 0x10 - v2.9.20419.2

Microsoft JVM Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting the Visual Studio debugger to JDWP compatible Java Virtual Machines

Microsoft MI-Based Debugger   1.0
Provides support for connecting Visual Studio to MI compatible debuggers

Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards   1.0
Microsoft Visual C++ Wizards

Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package   1.0
Microsoft Visual Studio VC Package

NuGet Package Manager   5.1.0
NuGet Package Manager in Visual Studio. For more information about NuGet, visit https://docs.nuget.org/

ProjectServicesPackage Extension   1.0
ProjectServicesPackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Python   16.1.19129.1
Provides IntelliSense, projects, templates, debugging, interactive windows, and other support for Python developers.

Python - Conda support   16.1.19129.1
Conda support for Python projects.

Python - Django support   16.1.19129.1
Provides templates and integration for the Django web framework.

Python - IronPython support   16.1.19129.1
Provides templates and integration for IronPython-based projects.

Python - Profiling support   16.1.19129.1
Profiling support for Python projects.

Python - VC Project Support   16.1.19129.1
Provides support for launching C++ projects with Python debugging enabled.

ResourcePackage Extension   1.0
ResourcePackage Visual Studio Extension Detailed Info

Test Adapter for Boost.Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Boost.Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

Test Adapter for Google Test   1.0
Enables Visual Studio's testing tools with unit tests written for Google Test.  The use terms and Third Party Notices are available in the extension installation directory.

TypeScript Tools   16.0.10506.2004
TypeScript Tools for Microsoft Visual Studio

Visual Basic Tools   3.1.1-beta4-19281-06+58a4b1e79aea28115e66b06f850c83a3f1fcb6d3
Visual Basic components used in the IDE. Depending on your project type and settings, a different version of the compiler may be used.

Visual C++ for Linux Development   1.0.9.28917
Visual C++ for Linux Development

Visual Studio Code Debug Adapter Host Package   1.0
Interop layer for hosting Visual Studio Code debug adapters in Visual Studio

Visual Studio Tools for CMake   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for CMake

Visual Studio Tools for CMake   1.0
Visual Studio Tools for CMake

### console app

```
#include <iostream>
#include "StaticLibTest\\framework.h"

int main()
{
    std::cout << "Hello World!\n";
    fnStaticLibTest();
}
```

### library header

```
#pragma once

#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN             // Exclude rarely-used stuff from Windows headers

void fnStaticLibTest();
```

### library code

```
#include "pch.h"
#include "framework.h"

// TODO: This is an example of a library function
void  fnStaticLibTest()
{
}
```

1>ConsoleApplication1.obj : error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl fnStaticLibTest(void)" (?fnStaticLibTest@@YAXXZ) referenced in function _main

Comment: Something went wrong with the "I add the reference" step.  Like forgetting to take the step.  Adding the .lib explicitly is a fine workaround.

Answer (score 2):

Found the problem. I was adding the reference clicking right button on the console project and then "Build dependencies" -> "Project dependencies". That didn't work but it works if I add it right-clicking references and then "Add Reference"